# DataAnnotations - Validator.TryValidateObject does not validate when no error message is specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I've just written an extension method to provide validation on DataContracts before squirting them over the wire to my API.

The extension menthod is:

```
    public static bool IsValid(this object obj, out List<ValidationResult> validations)
    {
        ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(obj, null, null);
        validations = new List<ValidationResult>();
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, validations, true);
    }
```

For brevity I'll just list one property on an object I'm validating:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "X coordinate")]
    [Range(-50, 50)]
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int XCo { get; set; }
```

If you set this property to 51 and validate it, it returns true!

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "X coordinate")]
    [Range(-50, 50, ErrorMessage="Xco outside accepted range")]
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int XCo { get; set; }
```

If you set this property to 51 and validate it, it returns false!

Even with a null ErrorMessage I wouldn't expect the Validator to return true on an invalid object just because a user supplied string property isn't set.

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure this to properly validate even if the error message property isn't set?

I know this isn't necessarily a good solution as good error reporting is obviously very useful but I would rather this process be data-centric.